# Join 2 records in 1 table with 2 records in another table to produce 2 records

Tags: sql, join, cross-join

I have 2 tables with lots of data that I need to join.  The problem is that the 2 tables hold mostly the same data, and the join sometimes produces undesired, though not unexpected. results.  Here is an example:

```
week_end_date  nugly   payroll_code  rate      hours     check_number
--------------------------------------------------------------
2010-01-17     AU9T8K  HRLY-W        13.00000  40.00000  530957               
2010-01-17     AU9T8K  HRLY-W        13.00000  40.00000  DD00000105382 

week_end_date   nugly   trx_number  pay_code    hours   rate
2010-01-17  AU9T8K  ETS00000010771815   HRLY-W  40.00000    13.00000
2010-01-17  AU9T8K  ETS00000010771684   HRLY-W  40.00000    13.00000
```

I'm looking to the the check # and the trx_number combined in the join, but I end up with a cross join because everything is the same that I'm joining on.  For every case I have like this, I really don't care with trx_number ends up with which check #.

Any thoughts?

Here are the current results:

```
week_end_date   nugly   payroll_code    rate    hours   check_number    trx_number
2010-01-17  AU9T8K  HRLY-W  13.00000    40.00000    DD00000105382           ETS00000010771815
2010-01-17  AU9T8K  HRLY-W  13.00000    40.00000    530957                  ETS00000010771815
2010-01-17  AU9T8K  HRLY-W  13.00000    40.00000    DD00000105382           ETS00000010771684
2010-01-17  AU9T8K  HRLY-W  13.00000    40.00000    530957                  ETS00000010771684
```

What I'd like is:

```
week_end_date   nugly   payroll_code    rate    hours   check_number    trx_number
2010-01-17  AU9T8K  HRLY-W  13.00000    40.00000    DD00000105382           ETS00000010771815
2010-01-17  AU9T8K  HRLY-W  13.00000    40.00000    530957                  ETS00000010771684
```

Where I don't really care which trx_number is with which check_number.

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT c.week_end_date, c.nugly, c.payroll_code, c.rate, c.hours, c.check_number, t.trx_number
    FROM checksByNuglyPaycode c 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN trxNumByNuglyPaycode t ON c.db_id = t.db_id AND c.fridate = t.fridate
        AND c.nugly = t.nugly AND c.trx_type = t.trx_type AND c.payroll_code = t.pay_code
        AND c.hours = t.hours AND c.rate = t.rate AND c.week_end_date = t.week_end_date
    WHERE t.db_id = 'lal' AND c.nugly = 'AU9T8K' AND c.payroll_code = 'HRLY-W' 
        AND c.fridate = '2010-01-22' AND c.week_end_date = '2010-01-17'
ORDER BY c.fridate, c.nugly, payroll_code
```

The where clause is obviously specifically for this case, in the final query, there will not be a where clause.

Comment: Can you show us the code you've tried and expected results?

Comment: Pls don't use tabs when posting content on SO -- makes formatting a nightmare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a guess, but could you use something like ROW_NUMBER to make a sort of identity field for each table and then join on them?

Something like

```
CREATE VIEW vwOrderedTable1
AS
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY week_end_date) AS 'RowNumber', 
    week_end_date, 
    nugly, 
    payroll_code...
FROM Table1
GO

CREATE VIEW vwOrderedTable2
AS
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY week_end_date) AS 'RowNumber', 
    week_end_date, 
    nugly, 
    'payroll_code' = pay_code...
FROM Table2
GO

SELECT *
FROM vwOrderedTable1 
INNER JOIN vwOrderedTable2 ON vwOrderedTable1.RowNumber = vwOrderedTable2.RowNumber
```

Comment: I'll look into that.  That looks promising; I've never really had an occasion to use OVER().

Comment: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Comment: I can't guarantee that both tables will hold the same number of rows, and therefore be able to be ordered the same way.

Comment: what determines that the first row in the first table is related to the second row in the second table? - sorry - just saw you don't care which is related to which.

Comment: @spuppett: If, as you say, the two tables are not guaranteed to have the same number of rows ('for the same data', I assume you mean), then how would you pick your random `trx_number` values to supply the result set with in case the tables do have different numbers of rows? With ROW_NUMBER there is a way (albeit somewhat different from Alex's) to match every row from table 1 with one, different each time, `trx_number` from table 2. Or would it be fine to match with just one and the same?

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide a bit more information?  What's your current query look like? How are the tables structured?  Are you trying to join on keys?

You mention you're "looking" to the check # and trx_number...  are these the results?

Do you have an example of what would be returned for the lines you've provided?

---

I like Alex's answer, it seems solid.

Perhaps a silly comment, but if you don't care what trx_number you get, and in your sample query you're using a left join that implies you only want "all" the data from checksByNuglyPaycode, why are you joining the two tables?  do you need all the data for both tables?  More like a full outer join?

So if there is a record in checksByNuglyPaycode that is not in trxNumByNuglyPaycode you would need it?

And if there is a record in trxNumByNuglyPaycode and not in checksByNuglyPaycode you would need that?

---

Interesting aside, if you do want all the data from both tables you could use the select below.  Note: it uses distinct which would likely be slow, and I think full outer joins can also be slow...  it's been quite a while...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ISNULL(c.week_end_date, t.week_end_date), ISNULL(c.nugly,t.nugly), 
    ISNULL(c.payroll_code,t.payroll_code), ISNULL(c.rate,t.rate), 
    ISNULL(c.hours, t.hours), c.check_number, t.trx_number
FROM 
    checksByNuglyPaycode c 
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    trxNumByNuglyPaycode t ON c.db_id = t.db_id 
                           AND c.fridate = t.fridate
                           AND c.nugly = t.nugly 
                           AND c.trx_type = t.trx_type 
                           AND c.payroll_code = t.pay_code
                           AND c.hours = t.hours 
                           AND c.rate = t.rate 
                           AND c.week_end_date = t.week_end_date
ORDER BY 
    c.fridate, c.nugly, payroll_code
```

Comment: This should be added as a comment under the original question rather than an answer in its own right :)

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to format stuff nicely under here, so I added it above.

Comment: Usually I do care about which trx_number, it's just in these edge cases, as long as I get one of the trx_numbers with one of the check_numbers, I'm good.  There are many more trx_numbers then there are check_numbers in our system, which is why I'm doing a left join; I don't need all the trx_numbers, but I do need all the check_numbers

Comment: In that case Alex's Answer seems like the correct one to me!  :-)

Comment: I think what I'm going to have to do is identify the ones that are wrong (which isn't too hard), and then do some voodoo on those outside of the basic select from above.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like the query you've already got as a sub-query wrapped up with:

```
SELECT MAX(trx_number), week_end_date, nugly, payroll_code, rate, hours, check_number
FROM
(
    QUERY_YOU_ALREADY_HAVE
) tbl
GROUP BY week_end_date, nugly, payroll_code, rate, hours, check_number
```

Comment: That's very close, but in my test case the 2 check numbers are getting the same trx_number, and I'd like to get one of each.